# Express not catching request to '/'

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have a quite bizzare issue - somehow, Express does not capture my request to my root route.

My Route File looks to following:

```
'use strict';

var errors = require('./components/errors');
var auth = require('./controllers/auth');
var ensureLoggedIn = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn;
module.exports = function(app) {

  // Insert routes below

  // All undefined asset or api routes should return a 404
  app.route('/:url(api|auth|components|app|bower_components|assets)/*')
   .get(errors[404]);

  app.route('/login')
    .get(auth.login)
    .post(auth.loginUser);
  app.route('/logout')
    .get(auth.logout);
  // All other routes should redirect to the index.html
  app.route('/*')
    .get(ensureLoggedIn('/login'), function(req, res) {
      console.log("req to /");
      res.sendfile(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html');
    });

};
```

So what happens:

- I request '/' and it sends me directly to my root and the app runs. Except: It does not require me to login, and also the Log Output does not show that any request has been made.
- If i request '/users' (Angular Route) it redirects me to '/login', as expected and then continues on its path.

Any idea what would be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's related to the filename of the 'main' Page being served, before Angular takes over.

Originally, the file was names **index.html** which, as it seems like, prompted Node to serve it by default - Which is expected behavior, if no routes interfere.
After renaming the *main* file to **application.html** and changing the serve asset - all is well, problem solved.

I am still unsure though, why the Route would not fire and the index would overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you exposing any static assets with express? If you are and you require your routes after you expose the assets, the request to "/" will just land in your public folder and do nothing.

Does this help? Could you post your **server.js**?

I ran into this issue earlier and it was driving me nuts.